# Видоизменение URL Opencart 2.3

Tags: php, opencart

Может кто решал, интересует вопрос как сделать чтобы у товаров и категорий были ссылки

```html
http://site.ru/product/tovar.html
```

и категория соответственно:

```html
http://site.ru/category/maslo
```

То есть по сути добавить приставки "product" и "category". 
Также важно чтоб это работало под seoPro.

Варианты с категориями и подстановкой в поля seourl значений со слешами не подходят.

Comment: seo url  в настройках магазина включите. А .html подписывать через .htaccess

Comment: Я наверное просто не полностью расписал, все включено, используется SeoPro, пол seourl заполнены.

Comment: то есть ссылка заполнена вида "tovar" а на сайте нужно получить вывод http://site.ru/product/tovar.html, не принципиально насчет html в конце